# How to Push from presented ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

What I want to do is:

**VC1 -> present VC2 -> push VC3**

this is the normal flow I want to make.

after that on **back** button(on each VC have back button)

I required to show user as moving back:

**VC3 -> present VC2 -> VC1**

How do I achieve this kind of navigation in Swift 5?

Comment: VC2 needs to be in a `UINavigationController` then after you present it you can push VC3. The back button will work as expected on VC3, for VC2 you should call [dismiss](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) when the back button is pressed. Try implementing some of that in code and then update your question.

Answer (score 12):

```
//VC1
@IBAction func presentVC2() {
    let vc2 = VC2()
    vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//VC2
@IBAction func presentVC3() {
    let vc3 = VC3()
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc3) //Add navigation controller
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//VC3
@IBAction func navigationVC4() {
    let vc4 = VC4()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc4, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ Ramprasath Selvam .

Comment: this works like a charm. and well explained. great.

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:):

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
> controller it presented.

so you need to dismiss it first then you can navigate to the viewController you want and you can implement it in the completion of `dismiss` function